# How to add the current client directory to the log file name?

Tags: java, log4j

I've been struggling with this problem in subject.

I tried something like this:

```
String sCurrDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
int nLastBSlash = sCurrDir.lastIndexOf('/');
System.setProperty("current.folder", sCurrDir.substring(nLastBSlash + 1));
```

and added the following to the log4j.properties:

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
  <param name="append" value="true" />
  <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
  <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="50" />

  <param name="File" value="./log/${current.folder}-wcss-simulator-${current.date}.log"/>

  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}\t %-5p\t [%X{ThreadId}]\t %X{MethodName}\t - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

But the file name only starts with an hyphen.

Comment: Log4j gets initialized at the time of application start. If you really want to achieve this, you need to add your own Appender which extends org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. First of all, you must clearly specify log4j2 rather than just log4j as both APIs are very different. You already have a DOT (.) in the File param which represents current folder. You should use log4j2.properties instead of log4j.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't work because logging has already started **before** you set the `current.folder` property. Do you have access to the program's `main` method or is this a container based application?

If you have access to the `main` method you have to make sure the first thing you do is set that property, before creating the first `Logger` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing your own Appender like:

```
import org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender;    
public class CustomFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {

        public CustomFileAppender() {
            super();
            String sCurrDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            int nLastBSlash = sCurrDir.lastIndexOf('/');
            System.setProperty("current.folder", sCurrDir.substring(nLastBSlash + 1));
        }
    }
```

Configure log4j properties/xml file as:

```
<appender name="fileAppender" class="CustomFileAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
      <param name="append" value="true" />
      <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
      <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="50" />

      <param name="File" value="./log/${current.folder}-wcss-simulator-${current.date}.log"/>

      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS}\t %-5p\t [%X{ThreadId}]\t %X{MethodName}\t - %m%n" />
      </layout>
   </appender>
```

Comment: I am working with Log4j2, It doesn't recognize the RollingFileAppender. How can I modify the code to work? Thanks

Comment: This class should be there even if you are using log4j2. I have updated the import in the code. Please try with this.

Comment: no. It still shows an error. I added dependencies for log4j api 2.82 and log4j core 2.8.2. Is that correct? Also, it offers me to change the base class to RollingFileManager instead.

Comment: You need bridge like log4j-over-slf4j for  RollingFileAppender if I am not wrong.